# Python: find the maximum

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series

```
reg_s_lag
Out[71]: 
X1             1.0
X2             1.0
X3             13.0
X4             13.0
X5             16.0
X6             2.0
X7             16.0
X8             16.0
X9             16.0
X10            2.0
Name: max_pos_arg, dtype: float64
```

I would like to have a new series so that all the value are lower bounded by 2.0. That is, to turn X1 and X2 to 2.0 while keeping all the other elements as they are. How may I do it? 
This does not work:

```
max(reg_s_lag, 2)
```

Comment: Hi, is `2.0` is a const value?

Comment: `df[df<2.0] = 2.0`

Comment: @DavidDr90 2.0 is a constant.

Comment: There are a lot of ways, `df[df<2]=2.0` or `df[df.lt(2)] = 2.0` or `df.apply(lambda x: x if x>=2 else 2.0)`. Note 1st two change the original `df` the last solution return a new `df` with desired values.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will replace all values less than a threshold value:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "X1": 1.0,
    "X2": 1.0,
    "X3": 13.0,
    "X4": 13.0,
    "X5": 16.0,
    "X6": 2.0,
    "X7": 16.0,
    "X8": 16.0,
    "X9": 16.0,
    "X10": 2.0
}

threshold = 2.0
reg_s_lag = pd.Series(data)
reg_s_lag[reg_s_lag<threshold] = threshold
print(reg_s_lag)
```

Output:

```
X1      2.0
X2      2.0
X3     13.0
X4     13.0
X5     16.0
X6      2.0
X7     16.0
X8     16.0
X9     16.0
X10     2.0
dtype: float64
```

Here I have used `threshold = 2.0`.